# Как запустить flask app и Discord bot в одном python файле

Tags: python, многопоточность

я делаю простенький веб сервер для авторизации в моём клиенте
но я не хочу делать веб приложение, а управлять базой данных через дискорд бота
так вот, как мне их обоих запустить

```
from flask import Flask, request
import discord, sqlite3, os, json
from discord.ext import commands
from threading import Thread

SECRET_KEY = "[=N,PNO<REt3^wG@cLbE;H\XkPwxp]4e_#L>5-K.O+K]o>\№Fz#cB)KGAh#s"

bot = commands.Bot(command_prefix="\\", status=discord.Status.dnd, activity=discord.Game(name="EntityWare"))
@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    print("Bot is ready!")

app = Flask(__name__)
app.config.from_object(__name__)

app.config.update(dict(DATABASE=os.path.join(app.root_path, 'database.db')))

def connect_db():
    conn = sqlite3.connect(app.config['DATABASE'])
    conn.row_factory = sqlite3.Row
    return conn

@app.route('/auth')
def auth():
    return 'Hello World!'

def startDiscordBot():
    bot.run("<token>")

def startFlaskWebserver():
    app.run(debug=True)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    Thread(target=startFlaskWebserver()).start()
    Thread(target=startDiscordBot()).start()
```

Comment: Документацию threading для начала почитать

Comment: @СергейШашко вы можете сказать как это сделать или нет?

Answer (score 0):

```
if __name__ == '__main__':
     threading.Thread(target = startFlaskWebserver).start() 
     startDiscordBot()
```

Flask запускаем в потоке, а DiscordBot работает в основном потоке

Comment: не работает, выдаёт ошибку `RuntimeError: can't register atexit after shutdown`

Comment: поправил ответ.